# Why is my array out of range?

Tags: vb.net

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Module Module1
 Sub Main()
    Dim HowMany As Integer
    Dim nameArray(HowMany) As String
    Dim HourlyWageArray(HowMany) As Double
    Dim HoursWorkedArray(HowMany) As Integer
    Dim GrossPayArray(HowMany) As Double
    Dim x As Integer = 0

    Console.WriteLine("How many employees?")
    HowMany = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    Do While x < HowMany
        Console.WriteLine("Employee name: ")
        nameArray(x) = CStr(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("Hourly rate: ")
        HourlyWageArray(x) = CDbl(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("Hours worked: ")
        HoursWorkedArray(x) = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        If HoursWorkedArray(x) <= 40 Then
            GrossPayArray(x) = HourlyWageArray(x) * HoursWorkedArray(x)
        ElseIf HoursWorkedArray(x) > 40 Then
            GrossPayArray(x) = ((HoursWorkedArray(x) - 40) * (HourlyWageArray(x) * 1.5)) + (40 * HourlyWageArray(x))
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("{0,12:c} {1,12} {2,12:c} {3,12:c}", nameArray, HourlyWageArray, HoursWorkedArray, GrossPayArray)


    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

At line 17, nameArray(x) = CStr(Console.ReadLine()), I receive an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred"

No matter what value I input for HowMany, This error occurs when trying to enter the 2nd employee name.

Comment: Think about this:

`y = 2; z = x + y; x = 1;` Why won't that work?

Comment: Because x hasn't been declared yet...but I can't put x=0 inside the loop can I?

Comment: Yep, so you're running into the same thing here. The `HowMany` defaults to 0 and then you use it before you assign the value.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining HowMany after you declare your arrays.  nameArray is defined on line three, when HowMany is probably 0, so nameArray will have zero entries.  You should read HowMany from the console before defining nameArray.

Comment: Thank you so much. An additional, unrelated question, How do I get the results to print correctly. Do I insert (x) after the array names for my last ConsoleWite?